# В android'e при парсинге jsoup'ом загружается не весь html текст

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

Доброго. В android'e парсится html сайта. Вот такое примитивный код:

```
class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
public String desc;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.ru").get();
        desc = document.html();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i("test", desc);
}
}
```

При этом загружается только часть html кода, прерывается на случайном месте. При проверке в Eclipse всё хорошо отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

@ЮрийСПБ
@metalurgus
Не думаю, что проблема с выводом текста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем при получении html'a посредством HttpUrlConnection'а та же самая несуразица :с
Дело не в том, что в странице отсутствуют какие-то блоки. Код прерывается на случайном месте, может вообще на половине названия тега. Вряд ли, это это из-за особенностей String'а или логов. Делал построчное выведение в логи с помощью InputStream'a - результат тот же. (!) К тому же, посмотрите, пожалуйста, на последний скрин, там я делал выборку по тегу 'а'. Ничего не нашлось. (!) В eclipse всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: вы ошибаетесь, он загружает документ полностью. Обрезать его может, например, сам лог. Или даже метод `toString()` у `Document `может обрезать его.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.ru").maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Решает проблему `maxBodySize(0)` который снимает ограничение на размер страницы, так же можно убрать `timeout(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Страница, находящаяся по адресу, который вы загружаете (`http://www.google.ru`) не имеет `HTML` кода(кроме тегов `html`, `head`, `sctipt`), а все содержимое на ней генерируется при помощи `JavaScript` динамически. Это значит, что вы получаете весь код страницы, но `JSOUP` не запускает работу `JavaScript`.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK
  Дело не в том, что в странице отсутствуют какие-то блоки. Код прерывается на случайном месте, может вообще на половине названия тега.
  Вряд ли, это это из-за особенностей String'а или логов. Делал построчное выведение в логи с помощью InputStream'a - результат тот же.
  (!) К тому же, посмотрите, пожалуйста, на последний скрин, там я делал выборку по тегу 'а'. Ничего не нашлось.
  (!) В eclipse всё прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело тут не в том, что не весь `HTML` загрузился, а в том, что `Log` просто не весь текст вывел.

Попробуйте разбить полученную строку на небольшие части и вывести их в цикле, по очереди.

Ну или просто попробуйте через Jsoup обратиться к последнему тегу в загруженной `HTML`-ке.

Answer (score 0):

Metalurgus Прав, сам сталкивался с такой проблемой. Проблема в том, что вы скачиваете HTML страничку, но JS скрипты не выполняются и поэтому вы не видите полной картины

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Мне один только `maxBodySize(0)` не помог. У меня появился весь код когда прописала:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(mLink).maxBodySize(0).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)" +
      "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
      .timeout(0).get();
```