# Jsoup. Документ парсится только до середины

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Здравствуйте. 
Пишу приложение для андроид, которое парсит с копроративной странички график работы. На исходной странице имеется одна таблица, в которой содержатся графики на все 12 месяцев для каждого сотрудника отдела. Всего в таблице около 600-650 строк.
При выполнении этого кода:

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url.htm").get();`

в doc, как и положено, сохраняется документ. Однако следующее выражение:

```
doc.select("tr").size();
```

возвращает число 451. Первые 451 строк парсятся без проблем (почти), а где остальные?

Вот кусок когда исходной страницы:

```html
<tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl9817500 style='height:12.75pt;border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6817500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl12217500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl12217500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13817500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13117500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13117500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl10517500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl9817500 style='height:12.75pt;border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6717500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6917500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6817500 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl12217500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl12217500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13817500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13117500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl13117500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl10517500 style='border-top:none'>0</td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
  <td class=xl6553517500></td>
 </tr>
```

Из таких tr и td состоит вся страница. Я привел кусок, на котором и обрывается документ. Скачаный jsoup'ом документ doc заканчивается на второй (в приведенном коде) tr, на 23-й по счету td. 
Насколько я понимаю, таблица сформирована автоматически:

```html
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
<!--Следующие сведения были подготовлены мастером публикации веб-страниц
Microsoft Excel.-->
<!--При повторной публикации этого документа из Excel все сведения между тегами
DIV будут заменены.-->
<!----------------------------->
<!--НАЧАЛО ФРАГМЕНТА ПУБЛИКАЦИИ МАСТЕРА ВЕБ-СТРАНИЦ EXCEL -->
<!----------------------------->
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть содержимое `doc`.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, нашел ответ на свой вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466678/%D0%92-androide-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-jsoup%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)

в моем случай проблема решилась методом .maxBodySize(0).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url.htm").maxBodySize(0).get();
```